# How do I deal with players that do not put much effort on character background?

Tags: gm-techniques, roleplaying

My group is, on its majority, formed by young players. Even though we have shared Game Table for 4 years and are close friends of mine, they have a tendency to make shallow characters and observe my NPCs "steal" the spotlight. However I have a player that over develops his character and makes the rest of the PCs look "unimportant", not because he tries to steal spotlight, but because the rest of the guys never have ideas for character development.

How can I encourage my players to make their characters more in depth, speak more than a few lines, and become more active?

Comment: Remember: if you find yourself asking for "any tips", the question isn't focused enough yet to be answerable here.

Comment: System would be useful to know here, as answers will be different depending on whether you're playing in games with niche protection, or a pre-game backstory gimmick, or mechanics for spotlighting, etc.

Comment: While I voted to put on hold, please do edit and refocus the question and maybe split it into several because there's a lot of potential there!!!

Comment: This sounds like the beginnings of a question on how to get players to create engaging characters.  To get a really good answer, you're going to need to refine this a bit - what system is it?   What kind of not-that-interesting characters are they making?  Most importantly, what is the real root of the problem with these characters?  And as an aside, do your *players* think that their characters are just fine, and if so, why?

Comment: There are two unfocused subjects here, too: backgrounds, and roleplaying during the game. Pick one to focus on, or if they're not separable, figure out what the common root problem is.

Answer (score 6):

There's more than one way to come up with a backstory.  Some of us can be told to write two pages of history and personality and we'll just do it.  That's great.  But it's not the only way to flesh out a character.

I've met players who need a little more prodding.  You can do this by giving them a set of questions to answer about the character.  A full page is daunting when you've got no ideas.  Describing something more guided like relationship with parents, first adventure, etc in a couple sentences is easier to handle.  Break up what you want into smaller, bite sized units and let the players answer those.

Even that is too much for some players though.  It still feels like homework.  What I've done in that case is switch to collaborative brainstorming mode.  Sit down with the player and take notes on the character.  Ask the same sort of questions you would have above, but ask them one at a time and go off track if something you want to explore comes up.  This is actually a really fun approach but it's often too time demanding to do for every player every game.

Finally, some players would rather have their character emerge in game play.  What I like to do with these players is to run them a private session before game start.  Give them a chance to feel out the character without the rest of the party watching.  Players are a little more bold with their characters when they're alone.  They don't have the option of hiding behind the character with more personality.  They do however have the option of taking timeout to discuss character with the GM to figure out some motivation.  As above, this is really fun but really time demanding.

Comment: I would add that you can combine your two approaches. Why not have an NPC ask the PC about his or her family life, first adventure, ect.?

Comment: @acbabis, if you can pull that off, great.  Whenever I've done that it's felt like a tangent.  It also puts the player on the spot if they aren't expecting it.